# How can generate numbers from given number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a generator which will keep generate numbers from a number that i give..

Let's say:

```js
function GenerateCombinations(data) {
  var x = number; //0122
  // So i want to generate numbers starting from that one i set.
  // For example:
  // 0123
  // 0124
  // 0125
  // ...
  // 0129
  // 0130
  // 0131
  // ...
  // 0199
  // 0200
  
}

GenerateCombinations("0122");
```

How can i archive it? :/ May i split it, and use setInterval or something?
Sorry i am noob at this tho.

Comment: `function* gen(x) { let match = x.match(/(0*)(\d+)/); if (match === null) return; let zeroes = match[1], num = +match[2]; while(true) yield zeroes + num++; }`

Comment: Hm... i've tried to use it but i am getting gen {<suspended>} in console.

Comment: read the [MDN article about generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and related, potentially a tutorial on how to use them.

Comment: Note that in hindsight, i should have ensured the input is the entire string:  `/^(0*)(\d+)$/`, but comments are there to give hints or notes, not for full code with error handling anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generator and take the number as new [`next`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next) value.

```js
function* generate(value) {
    var temp;
    while (true) {
        temp = yield ++value;
        if (temp !== undefined) {
            value = temp;
        }
    }
}

var iterator = generate(122);

console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next(300).value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next(0).value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a real generator function:

```
function* range(start) {
  let value = +start;
  while(true) {
    const str = "" + value;
    yield "0".repeat(start.length - str.length) + str;
    value++;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but like above i am getting range {<suspended>} in console. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can't of course generate an infinite number of values, you need to choose how many new values you want to have. This can easily be achieved with a for loop. [Reference ad W3](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Here we take the starting value x and assign it to our counter i, it will cycle untile i mets the numbersToGenerate which is the amount of values you want to generate.

```
for (i = x; i < numbersToGenerate; i++) {
    // print your new value or manipulate it as you wish
}
```